# How to deal with dynamically changing input tensor in neural networks without padding?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, deep-neural-networks, pytorch, graph-neural-networks

I have a dataset about the monitored health/growth of a community of people. The dataset has tensor shaped `(batch_size, features, person, window)`, where:

- person==10 means there are 10 people in the community
- features==9 means that there are 9 features being monitored, for example, blood pressure, sugar level, ..etc
- window==15 means the recorded value of each feature every day for 15 days (time dimension)

Moreover, people can join/leave the community, so the person dimension would increase/decrease over time. For simplicity, the window dimension is fixed at 15, then a new person that joined has to be in the community for a minimum of 15 days to be included in the dataset as 1 data point/sample. Also, say the number of features is fixed at 9. Hence, for this problem, only the number of people at an instance may change over each input interaction.

For example, **assume batch_size==1** then the input dimension into the neural network would be something like:

```
Iter 1: (1, 9, 7, 15)
Iter 2: (1, 9, 7, 15)
Iter 3: (1, 9, 7, 15)
Iter 4: (1, 9, 8, 15) # 1 person joins the community
Iter 5: (1, 9, 8, 15)
Iter 6: (1, 9, 7, 15) # 1 person left the community
Iter 7: (1, 9, 6, 15) # 1 person left the community
Iter 8: (1, 9, 6, 15)
Iter 9: (1, 9, 10, 15) # 4 person joins the community
```

Is there a way to deal with this dynamically changing input tensor in neural networks without padding? As we won't know in advance how many people will join/leave the community (related to continual learning?) hence won't know the maximum pad.

Also, how to deal when `batch_size` is **not** 1?

Comment: So, each community contains certain number of people, and each of them has specific characteristics? You want to infer something about the community, based on it's residents?

Comment: What is the target variable you are trying to predict?